# Class systems with nth-of-type

Tags: jquery, css, class, css-selectors

I'm confused as to how the nth-of-type function is actually supposed to work. I dunno if I've coded it wrong because I can't get it to operate properly. This is the structure I have- (Updated)

```
<div id="wrapper">

        <div id="slider">

            <div class="slide"> <a href="link> <img src="imglink" alt="Slide1">

                <div class="slide-block">
                    <h4>Header</h4>

                    <p>Subtext</p>
                </div> 
              </a>   
            </div>

            <div class="slide"> <a href="link"> <img src="imglink" alt="Slide2">
                <div class="slide-block">
                    <h4>Header</h4>
                    <p>Subext</p>
                </div>
              </a>  
            </div>

            <div class="slide"> <a href="link"> <img src="imglink" alt="Slide3">
                <div class="slide-block">
                    <h4>Header</h4>
                    <p>subtext</p>
                </div>
              </a>  
            </div>

        </div>  

    </div>
```

I'm trying to select nth(2) of the "slide" classes, but it will always select the first "slide" class.

```
        $('#thumbnails').click(function() {
                $('#slider').trigger('slideTo', $( "class.slider slide:nth-of-type(2))") );

        });
    });
```

In Firefox, I can only get it to select the first class type, not the second class. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: First off, IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: nth-of-type works with only element type

Comment: It works with classes as well.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, man, you aren't terminating your HTML tags:

```
 <div id="slider">
 <div class="slide">
     <a href="link"><img src="imglink">
 <div class="slide-block">
 <h4>Text</h4>
 <p>Subtext</p>
```

Do you see what is wrong with this? The browser can't figure out the children of `.slider`, because *I* can't figure out the children of `.slider`.

#### How to fix this, in case you don't know

Divs go like this:

```
<div class='slider'><!-- content inside --></div>
```

#### Sooo... what's the problem?

Improperly formatting HTML is good at hiding flaws in the HTML structure. Properly formatted, take a look at your code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="slider">
    <div class="slide">
      <a href="link"><img src="imglink">
        <div class="slide-block">
          <h4>Text</h4>
          <p>Subtext</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="slider">
      <div class="slide">
        <a href="link"><img src="imglink">
          <div class="slide-block">
            <h4>Text</h4>
            <p>Subtext</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="slider">
        <div class="slide">
          <a href="link"><img src="imglink">
            <div class="slide-block">
              <h4>Text</h4>
              <p>Subtext</p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
```

Do you see how the wrapper and the first pieces were never properly terminated? The browser is likely very confused with how to interpret your HTML.

#### How to handle it

This is where we give you your next assignment. Good Stack Overflow questions imply you have done decent work to try to solve the problem yourself. Study up on how to properly format this code, and then it should solve your problem.

Comment: Other than pointing out a flaw in the HTML, how does this actually answer the question? Probably should be a comment.

Comment: That's just how the code will work with what I already have. And I missed out a </div> to close the slider tag

Comment: @j08691 I updated my answer. However, I don't want Cameo to become a help vampire, so I pointed him in the right direction to solve his own problem.

Comment: Plus I cant have unique ID tags for everything as the slider won't properly recognize the class of "slide" so it can 'slideTo' it

Comment: That's true, @CameoCream, do fix that as well.

Comment: I'll update the original post, I condensed the code to make it easier to read. I think I removed some important things.

Comment: @CameoCream can you make a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g33H8/4/embedded/result/  Full screen fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/g33H8/4/light/     Code here